# \parboxes with facing pages in `eledmac`/`eledpar`

Tags: boxes, parallel, eledmac

Currently I'm trying to typeset a document with facing pages using `eledpar` and `eledmac`. On some pages I'd like to fill in images between paragraphs. In order to have a predictable height for these images I was using the `\parbox` command as a container for these images.
Now I got the hint that `\pstart` and `\pend` can take optional arguments with them, what seems to be the more clean solution. After having played around a bit I found out that the command

`\pend[\parbox{width}{content}]`

works perfectly while the same command where parbox takes some parameters won't compile properly

`\pend[\parbox[position][height][inner-pos]{width}{content}]`

I admit that the first parameter indeed doesn't make much sense in the facing pages environment, but it would be nice to control the height of the box manually. Thanks in advance for tipps and hints!

Comment: Use an additional pair of braces: `\pend[{\parbox[pos][ht][inn-pos]{width}{contents}}]`